# Sinon test failing after change made to function

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon

I have this test:

```
describe('createNote', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    res = {
      json: sinon.spy(),
      sendStatus: sinon.spy(),
    };
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    noteService.createUserNote.restore();
  });

  it('should return user note object', async () => {
    // Arrange
    modelResponse = {
      id: 1,
      userId: req.user.id,
      ...req.body,
    };
    sinon.stub(noteService, 'createUserNote')
      .resolves(modelResponse);

    // Act
    await userController.createNote(req, res);

    // Assert
    sinon.assert.calledWith(
      noteService.createUserNote,
      req.user,
      req.body.note,
    );
    sinon.assert.calledWith(res.json, { note: modelResponse });
  });
```

It fails on line `sinon.assert.calledWith(res.json, { note: modelResponse });`

I don't really understand sinon so I'm not sure why though.

This is my userController code:

```
createNote: async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const createNote = await noteService.createUserNote(
      req.user,
      req.body.note,
    );
    const note = await noteService.getUserNote(
      req.user.id,
      createNote.id,
    );
    return res.json({ note });
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
},
```

I recently changed it from this so assume something in what I've done has caused the test to fail:

```
createNote: async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const note = await noteService.createUserNote(
      req.user,
      req.body.note,
    );
    return res.json({ note });
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
},
```

This is the error I get:

```
  1) User userController
       createNote
         should return user note object:
     AssertError: async (user, text) => {
    const [note] = await db.Note.createUserNote(user.id, text, db);
    await emailService.userAlert(text, user.name);
    return note;
  } is not stubbed
      at Object.fail (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/assert.js:106:21)
      at /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/assert.js:35:24
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at verifyIsStub (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/assert.js:22:5)
      at Object.assert.(anonymous function) [as calledWith] (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/assert.js:77:9)
      at Context.it (app/__tests__/controllers/user/userController.test.js:56:20)
      at <anonymous>
```

Can anybody explain what is wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mock **getUserNote** as well. After the change, you are getting **note** from **getUserNote** and then sending it to **res.json**

But in the test case you have not stubbed it. Try adding this in the test case:

```
sinon.stub(noteService, 'getUserNote')
      .resolves(modelResponse);
```